# How to take a row from one DataGridView and copy it to another?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a project with winform where i did a user to double click on a row of a data grid view that contains BookId BookName and Genre and it should be added to another Dgv like a shopping cart.

```
private void DgvSearchResult_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    DgvCart.Rows.Add(DgvSearchResult.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridView>().ToArray());           
}
```

But the code above copies an empty row.

Comment: Use objects that bind to a datagrid. Then just bind the object of the selected row to an other datagrid. Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Is the DGV editable and contain a blank last row?  The code is probably copying the empty last row.

Comment: You need to create a new dgvRow anf copy all content over.

Comment: As TaW stated, you will have to “copy” the cell values into a “new” row. The [DataGridViewRow.Clone Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone?view=netframework-4.8) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used two datagridviews, origDgv that contained the data I was copying from and copyDgv, the datagridview I copied the data to.

This is the CellDoubleClick event from the DataGridView origDgv: -

```
    private void origDgv_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        string[] rowData = new string[origDgv.Columns.Count];
        int iOffset = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvCell in origDgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
        {
            if(dgvCell.EditedFormattedValue != null)
            {
                rowData[iOffset] = dgvCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();

            }
            iOffset++;
        }


        copyDgv.Rows.Add(rowData);
    }
```